# Inline padding styling confilcit between Chrome and FF/IE

Tags: html, css, inline

For some reasons, I have to apply inline td width in a table, see lower part of table at this page using Chrome at this [page](http://www.pemsea.org/publications/documents/pc6)

Firefox and IE seem to render this well, however, Chrome is rendering the width differently. Applying left and right paddings on tds, seem to have the same issues with Chrome.

Any ideas? Again, I need to do this inline. Global CSS seems to do render more issues with the site globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Remove `width=""` for all `td's`
and apply below css

CSS

```
.dataTables_wrapper table td {
  padding: 0.5em 0 0em 0;

}
.view-footer td:first-child,
.dataTables_wrapper table td:first-child {
    width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is allocating space for table column varying each browsers when you have not assign any width. so assign some width to your td will resolve the problem. Just add the following class in CSS to fix this problem.

```
 #datatable-1 tr td:first-child
 {
   width:1%;
 }
```